# no matching function for call to ‘ ’

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, compiler-errors, hashmap

Here's the definition of my class:

```
class F1Team {
    private:
        string name;
        string racer1;
        string racer2;

    protected:
        int titles;
    
    public:
        F1Team(string tnm) {
            name = tnm;
            titles = 0;
            
        }
        void set_racer1(string r1) {
            racer1 = r1;
        }
        void set_racer2(string r2) {
            racer2 = r2;
        }
        void display() {
            cout<< name<< endl;
        }
};
```

I want to store class objects mapping to an int (i.e., <int, [class]>)

Here's my code to implement it:

```
int main() {
    map<int, F1Team> mp;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        
        F1Team t {"Mercedes"};
        mp.insert(pair<int , F1Team>(i, t));
    }

    for (auto itr = mp.begin(); itr != mp.end(); ++itr) {
        (*itr).second.display();
    }
    mp[1].display();
    return 0;
}
```

The code throws compilation error when I try to access the object by key.

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/map:61,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/11/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = F1Team]’:
/usr/include/c++/11/tuple:1813:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {int&&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = F1Team]’
/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:162:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, F1Team>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:516:17:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const int, F1Team>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, F1Team> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_tree.h:595:32:   required from ‘void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_construct_node(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, F1Team>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >*]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_tree.h:612:21:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, F1Team>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >*]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_tree.h:2431:33:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_hint_unique(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<int&&>, std::tuple<>}; _Key = int; _Val = std::pair<const int, F1Team>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, F1Team>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, F1Team> > >::iterator; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<const int, F1Team>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, F1Team> > >::const_iterator]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_map.h:520:37:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = F1Team; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, F1Team> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = F1Team; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’
test.cpp:45:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/tuple:1824:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘F1Team::F1Team()’
 1824 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:17:9: note: candidate: ‘F1Team::F1Team(std::string)’
   17 |         F1Team(string tnm) {
      |         ^~~~~~
test.cpp:17:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: ‘F1Team::F1Team(const F1Team&)’
    7 | class F1Team {
      |       ^~~~~~
test.cpp:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: ‘F1Team::F1Team(F1Team&&)’
test.cpp:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I don't understand why the constructor to my class is being called here.

Comment: `operator[]` for `std::map` will create an object if the passed key is not present in the map, therefore it needs value type to be default constructible to be used (even if you always use it only on keys that are already in the map, compiler has no means of knowing that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mp[1]` promises to to default-construct a `F1Team` object, in case none currently exists with the key `1`.

Since your `F1Team` object can not be default-constructed, use `mp.at(1)` instead.  [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) will throw if the key is not present.